# Sony Vaio VPC-EC Series, CPU Temperature very high.

Tags: power-management, cpu, overheating, fan

I know this has been asked quite a few times before, but after some intense research I still could not fix my CPU problems.

I'm running Ubuntu on a Sony Vaio from the VPC-EC series. Under windows 7 I never got similar high temperatures nor FAN noise. 
On Ubuntu I have a constant temperature of about 55° and a very loud fan (e.g. when only firefox is running).

I already applied all hints from this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter) that works mainly with TLP to adjust Power Safe Options (i.e. CPU Usage and others)...

But I had almost no effect at all. Can anyone give me some advice on what to do next or how to find out what the problem is? I tried really a lot of stuff, but it seems that I just can't get this done properly.

Comment: It was an ATI driver problem. solved it as described here:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/286775#286775

Answer (score 2):

As you tagged your problems stems from the missing power-management drivers. I had similar issues with my Vaio VGN-SZ1XP and found some working drivers here: http://vaio-utils.org

Installation for the fan driver:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vaiofand/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vaiofand
```

Installation for the power-management driver:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vaiopower/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vaiopower
```

Your model isn't specifically listed, but with some luck this might still work.

Comment: unfortunately my model is not supported...

Answer (score 1):

This can get your battery to a good state but nothing is going to happen to fan
How to perform a calibration (full discharge)?

The most adequate method to do a full discharge (100% to a minimum of 3%) consists of the following procedure:

```
Fully charge the battery to its maximum capacity (100%);
Let the battery "rest" fully charged for 2 hours or more in order to cool down from the charging process. You may use the computer normally within this period;
Unplug the power cord and set the computer to hibernate automatically at 5% as described by the image sequence below (click images to enlarge). If you cannot select 5%, then you should use the minimum value allowed, but never below 5%;


Leave the computer discharging, non-stop, until it hibernates itself. You may use the computer normally within this period;
When the computer shuts down completely, let it stay in the hibernation state for 5 hours or even more;
Plug the computer to the A/C power to perform a full charge non-stop until its maximum capacity (100%). You may use the computer normally within this period.
```

After the calibration process, the reported wear level is usually higher than before. This is natural, since it now reports the true current capacity that the battery has to hold charge. Lithium Ion batteries have a limit amount of discharge cycles (generally 200 to 300 cycles) and they will retain less capacity over time.

Many people tend to think "If calibrating gives higher wear level, then it's a bad thing". This is wrong, because like said, the calibration is meant to have your battery report the true capacity it can hold, and it's meant to avoid surprises like, for example, being in the middle of a presentation and suddenly the computer shuts down at 30% of charge.

Comment: thanks for your useful hint! I will use it to hopefully increase batterly life. still the mayor problem is the hot CPU and the fact that I think my fan is maybe not working properly. i will try to contact Sony to see if there are any drivers available!

Comment: ok. good to contact sony but i prefer you to use a cooling pad also.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are are having a lot of addons and plugins installed in fire fox browser.Try to fix it. TLP is the best one for this. I too use the Sony vaio series laptop.

Comment: I have yes. but still...I had the same amount of addons installed on Windows 7 and not nearly as high temperatures nor noise...

Comment: Are you getting a good battery life and is it showing accurate results.How old is your laptop?

Comment: Battery life is shorter than under Windows but at least more accurate. The laptop is about one year and a half. It has very good Hardware components...this laptop-stand (http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004ARHYZS/ref=oh_details_o03_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) arrived today and seems to help me a little bit.

Comment: Its better to use a cooling pad than that stand.Natural air flow can't fix up the problem.